# Why does this code work in certain cases and in others it doesn't?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, return-value, rest-parameters

```js
const removeFromArray = function (array,...numbersToRemove) {
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(let a = 0; a < numbersToRemove.length; a++) {
            if(array[i] === numbersToRemove[a]) {
                const index = array.indexOf(numbersToRemove[a]);
                array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        }
        return array; 
    };

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 3));
```

This code works fine. However if you write `console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));` instead, it stops working. Simply because the `3` and the `2` are inverted. Why?

I believe it's because it loops from 0 to x and so if it's at loop nr. 3 then you give it a 2, it won't loop from 0 again it will continue looping from 3+ until the loop ends, right? So... how can I fix this?

PS. Please don't use arrow functions since I'm not there yet in my study path

Comment: Just… follow what this code does step by step…?! You can use https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html for that.

Comment: I did, it resets the loop from 0 for each new number so it works however I still don't get it why it doesn't work when the 3 and 2 are inverted.

Comment: Because when you remove `array[1]` (`2`), `array` becomes `[1, 3, 4]`. But it's now at the end of the inner for loop, so continues checking `array[2]` next. `3` has moved and has thereby skipped the check. Again, if you really go through it step by step, you should see this.

Comment: Since you are using  function and not an arrow function - just use arguments, rather than spreading unnecessarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `splice()` changes the array you are iterating over, which screws up your current position in the array if the removed position comes before the one your are at. If you invert the loops and go overt the `numbersToRemove` in the outer loop, it should work.

Overall, you can make it much simpler though by removing the outer loop altogether. The way it is, you are searching through `array` again anyway:

```js
const removeFromArray = function(array, ...numbersToRemove) {
  for (let a = 0; a < numbersToRemove.length; a++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] === numbersToRemove[a]) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
};

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

Or just:

```js
const removeFromArray = (arr, ...numbersToRemove) => arr.filter(e => !numbersToRemove.includes(e))
console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I don't get it though, how does splice changes array iteration? I ran that code through a debugger and it was so confusing to read. In a nested for loop, if we have one that's (1, 2, 3) and one that's (99, 88), it should show: 1, 99 - 1, 88 - 2,99 - 2,88 - 3,99 - 3,88 (or in 0s and 1s equivalents) but when I ran this code through a debugger it was so messy I couldn't understand anything... but anyway thanks for your help @Moritz Ringler

Comment: @Luigi Oh, I just realized I hadn't read your code careful enough. Things are much simpler, you don't need the outer loop at all. Have a look at the updated answer

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. I came up with that code at first myself but instead of looping ```i < numbersToRemove.length``` I looped ```i < array.length```. So why would you not loop through the array that you should iterate through? Instead you're looping through the one that the user writes as an input. You can see this original code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75477160/how-can-i-ignore-non-present-values-in-a-function-without-returning-undefined/75477318#75477318

Comment: @Luigi But you are looping through the array, even without the outer loop. It's the `const index = array.indexOf(numbersToRemove[a])`. In your original code, you are looping through it twice (once in `for` and once in `indexOf()`). You could also remove that line and use `i` instead of `index` - it's the same value. Have a look at the updated snipped (the first one, without the `indexOf()`)